# Why isn't the conditional statement working right?

Tags: powershell

I've got some Reports that I'm trying to loop through, and fetch the connection ID's (User ID's) and list those reports along with the usernames.

A report can have the following scenarios:

- No DataSources
- 1 DataSource (1 User ID)
- More than 1 DataSources (Therefore more than 1 user id's)

The following script does the job, however, for some reason, reports with only 1 datasource seem to be getting executed in the `else ... No Connection ID's found!` statement. That shouldn't be the case considering there is AT LEAST 1 Datasource, so they should be going through this `if ($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.count -gt 0)` statement instead!

Below is script accompanied by current output vs expected output:

```
$loopCount = 1
$PBI_Reports_Array = @()

$DataSourceQueue = New-Object System.Collections.Queue

try {
    $PBI_Reports_Array = $(Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $($webPortalURL + "/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports")) 

    foreach ($reportPath in $PBI_Reports_Array.value.path) {
        try {
            foreach ($DataSource in $(Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -uri $($webPortalURL + "/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports(path='" + $reportPath + "')/DataSources")))
            {
                $DataSourceQueue.Enqueue($DataSource)
            }
            
            while($DataSourceQueue.count)
            {   
                $DataSourceValue = $($DataSourceQueue.Dequeue()).value
                
                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($($DataSourceValue))) { 
                    write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | No DataSource connection exists for this Report!";
                }
                else {
                    if ($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.count -gt 0) #if there is at least 1+ DataSources and usernames...
                    {
                        #because there is more than 1 DataSources, that means there's also more than 1 connection ID and more than 1 connection ID's 
                        #to loop through both of those variables, foreach loop would not be suitable for more than 1 variable,
                        #so we use good old for loop
                        
                        0..($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.length-1) | ForEach-Object {
                                
                            write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource[$_].Username) | Retrieved!"
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.Username) | No Connection ID's found!"
                    }
                }
            }
            #$loopCount++
        }
        catch {
            write-host "$loopCount | ERROR! $($error[0])`r`n$($error[0].InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)`r`n$($error[0].ScriptStackTrace)"
        }
        $loopCount++
    }
}
catch { 
}
```

Current output:

```
1 | /Cash Flow/CFG | SI_123456_P | No Connection ID's found!
2 | /CPUR/DQ Dashboards | gp_powerbi_cpur | No Connection ID's found!
3 | /ABC/DQ Dashboards/PreCost ABC DQ Dashboard | gp_powerbi_cpur | Retrieved!
3 | /ABC/DQ Dashboards/PreCost ABC DQ Dashboard | SI_123456_P | Retrieved!
4 | /Prototypes/ARCHIVE/dummy data |  | No Connection ID's found!
```

Expected Output:

```
1 | /Cash Flow/CFG | SI_123456_P | Retrieved!
2 | /CPUR/DQ Dashboards | gp_powerbi_cpur | Retrieved!
3 | /ABC/DQ Dashboards/PreCost ABC DQ Dashboard | gp_powerbi_cpur | Retrieved!
3 | /ABC/DQ Dashboards/PreCost ABC DQ Dashboard | SI_123456_P | Retrieved!
4 | /Prototypes/ARCHIVE/dummy data |  | No Connection ID's found!
```

Note the 4th report has no connection ID's, therefore makes sense that the status is `No Connection ID's found!`. but reports 1 and 2 have 1 ID, so the status should be `Retrieved!` not `No Connection ID's found!` as it's currently displaying. For the 3rd report, it appears because it has more than 1 DataSource, the conditional statement is being applied correctly...

---

***EDIT:***

`$DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.GetType()`

yields:

for reports 1 & 2:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

for report 3:

```
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

---

***EDIT 2:***

```
62 | /test/BMI vs Chocolate |  | Retrieved!

Type                : Import
Kind                : File
AuthType            : Windows
SupportedAuthTypes  : {Windows}
Username            :
Secret              :
ModelConnectionName :

62 | /test/BMI vs Chocolate |  | Retrieved!

Type                : Import
Kind                : File
AuthType            : Windows
SupportedAuthTypes  : {Windows}
Username            :
Secret              :
ModelConnectionName :

62 | /test/BMI vs Chocolate |  | Retrieved!

Type                : Import
Kind                : File
AuthType            : Windows
SupportedAuthTypes  : {Windows}
Username            :
Secret              :
ModelConnectionName :

63 | /VP/Complexity_PROD | gp_powerbi_vp | Retrieved!

Id                                        : 12345-cvgfgh7-87964-e76ufhf5
Name                                      :
Description                               :
Path                                      :
Type                                      : DataSource
Hidden                                    : False
Size                                      : 0
ModifiedBy                                : user1
ModifiedDate                              : 2021-02-03T12:17:26.413-05:00
CreatedBy                                 : SI_123456_P
CreatedDate                               : 2021-02-03T12:13:42.523-05:00
ParentFolderId                            :
IsFavorite                                : False
ContentType                               :
Content                                   :
IsEnabled                                 : True
ConnectionString                          : db=maxisdb;driver={DataDirect 7.1 Greenplum Wire Protocol};em=1;host=gp.companyxyz.com;port=5432;vsc=0
DataSourceType                            :
IsOriginalConnectionStringExpressionBased : False
IsConnectionStringOverridden              : False
CredentialRetrieval                       : prompt
IsReference                               : False
DataSourceSubType                         : DataModel
Roles                                     : {}
CredentialsByUser                         :
CredentialsInServer                       :
DataModelDataSource                       : @{Type=Import; Kind=Odbc; AuthType=UsernamePassword; SupportedAuthTypes=System.Object[]; Username=gp_powerbi_vp; Secret=; ModelConnectionName=}

Type                : Import
Kind                : Odbc
AuthType            : UsernamePassword
SupportedAuthTypes  : {UsernamePassword, Anonymous, Windows}
Username            : gp_powerbi_vp
Secret              :
ModelConnectionName :
```

Comment: It should probably work fine by changing `if ($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.count -gt 0)` for `if ($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource)`

Comment: Obviously, I can't pull back this data to test. A guess is that `$DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource` is a string or other scalar value. If so it won't have a `.Count` property.  I'm not sure about the data structure, but `.Length` should work for both.  Though @SantiagoSquarzon suggestion may also work.

Comment: Also point out you seem to be using a lot of `$(...)` subexpressions. I'm not sure they are all needed, but where yes generally you can drop the `$` and just allow grouping/precedence `(...)`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon good suggestion, i tried `if ($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource)` but what is happening now is its printing the result twice for some reason...so it's saying retrieved, as it should, but its printing the record twice.

Comment: @Steven ya i usually dont utilize subexpressions but since ive started using SQL and since i'd be performing a lotta array indexing to get a value, i got used to subexpressions lol. also i tried the suggestion with `.length` and it didnt change the results, still saying `No connection ID's`

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint  or a debug message in that part of the code and execute `$DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.GetType()` If it's not a string it will not have a length property either. Moreover, seeing as the overload for `[IsNullOrEmpty]` takes a string it will coerce, but I don't know what the result will be...

Comment: I agree with @Steven, it's hard to tell without having the data to test. I also agree with him on `$DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource` not having a `Count` property when there is only 1 item. It would help us greatly if you can give us the object type when the variable contains just 1 value.

Comment: Well you reading my mind now @Steven lol

Comment: @Steven please see my edit. i included object type for both 1 datasource and more than 1 datasource scenarios

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon check out my edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't mean this as an answer but could you test your script by replacing this portion of code:

```
$DataSourceValue = $($DataSourceQueue.Dequeue()).value
                
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($($DataSourceValue))) { 
    write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | No DataSource connection exists for this Report!";
}
else
{
    if ($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.count -gt 0)
    {
        0..($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.length-1) | ForEach-Object {               
            write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource[$_].Username) | Retrieved!"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.Username) | No Connection ID's found!"
    }
}
```

For this:

```
$DataSourceValue = $DataSourceQueue.Dequeue().Value
                
if (-not $DataSourceValue)
{ 
    write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | No DataSource connection exists for this Report!";
}
else
{
    if ($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.Username)
    {
        foreach($i in $DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.Username)
        {                
            write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $i | Retrieved!"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $($DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource.Username) | No Connection ID's found!"
    }
}
```

Edit: Complete new script here, let's see if this works.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$loopCount = 1
$hash = @{
    UseDefaultCredentials = $true
}

try
{
    $hash.Uri = "$webPortalURL/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports"
    $PBI_Reports_Array = (Invoke-RestMethod @hash).Value.Path

    foreach ($reportPath in $PBI_Reports_Array)
    {
        $hash.Uri = "$webPortalURL/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports(path='$reportPath')/DataSources"
        
        try
        {
            $DataSourceQueue = (Invoke-RestMethod @hash).Value
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Warning ("$loopCount | ERROR! Can't connect to {0}" -f $hash.uri)
            continue
        }

        foreach ($value in $DataSourceQueue)
        {
            if (-not $value.DataModelDataSource)
            {
                    write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | No DataModelDataSource"
                    continue
            }

            foreach($i in $value.DataModelDataSource)
            {
                if($i.Username)
                {
                    $i.Username | foreach-object {
                        write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | $_ | Retrieved!"
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    write-host "$loopCount | $reportPath | DataModelDataSource Found but No Usernames"
                }
            }
        }
    $loopCount++
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning ("ERROR! Can't connect to {0}" -f $hash.uri)
}
```

Comment: Now i am getting `No DataSource connection exists for this Report!` for all reports

Comment: @Cataster I edited my code again, `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty( )` was definetly not the right way to check if the variable was null. Try it, if I got this right, you should never be entering the last `else` condition.

Comment: Awesome! That done the trick! :D pretty impressive considering no data to test with haha

Comment: @Cataster Wait lol, but tell me, did you ever enter the last `else` statement?

Comment: I threw in a +1 nice work.  I wish we could jump straight into chat...

Comment: oh wait some of the reports returned no usernames, yet it displayed a "retrieved" status. so weird, consdering many of the reports that returned no username returned "No Connection ID's" status. maybe it was supposed to return "No Datasources? so i think the `-not` is probably not working

Comment: @Cataster Let see, can you edit you answer displaying an example of how `$DataSourceValue` looks like and an example of how `$DataSourceValue.DataModelDataSource` looks like (this one preferable, one that has more than one `Username`)

Comment: `did you ever enter the last else statement?` yes it seems its entering the last else statement for reports with no id's. isnt that supposed to be the case?

Comment: please see EDIT2. the one showing retrieved even though theres no username is the BMI Chocolate report

Comment: @Cataster i added a new edit, lets see if that works. is very hard how the data looks like...

Comment: Ohhhh this one is displaying retrieved status for ALL reports, regardless whether there is a username or not

Comment: @Cataster Ok, last edit, if that doesn't work i'm out of ideas. sorry